# Is there a command to create a Cloud Firestore in Native mode database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I'm setting up a Google Cloud project, and want to create a Cloud Firestore in Native mode in a shell script.

There are commands to create cloud resources via gcloud for other products. For exmaple, we can create a kubernetes cluster by `gcloud container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] [--zone [COMPUTE_ZONE]]` (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster#zonal)

I would like know the command to create the Cloud Firestore in Native mode. I haven't had any luck finding it in the Firestore documentation (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers). The documentation only mentions how to do it in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to select the Firestore mode from an environment outside the Cloud Console (e.g. via Cloud SDK, API, etc.). However, there is already a request for this feature to be implemented.

You can track [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/133770824) for future updates by clicking the **star icon** on the top left hand corner so you will be updated whenever any new changes occur.